# How to remove YouTube video that infringes my IP?

Tags: copyright, music

If someone made a video of my song and uploaded it to YouTube: Is that legal?  If not, how can I block the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's copyright infringement, and is illegal under various copyright laws.

To take down the content, you'll have to make a claim under the Digital Millennium Copyright Act. The online form for making a takedown notice to YouTube under the DMCA can be found here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2807622?hl=en

Remember, that by submitting a takedown notice, that you are initiating a legal process. Take extra care not to abuse it, and to make sure that all information you submit is accurate.